# plsql oracle how to not allow for an employee's bonus be greater than 0.1% of the total quantity?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm new to sql and was wondering if anyone could help me debug my sql query using a trigger.

What I am trying to do is not allow for an employee's bonus be greater than 0.1% of the total quantity of stock they are accountable for. Can anyone please help me?

My code is as follows:

```
create or replace trigger check_employee_bonus
before update of Bonus or insert on employee
for each row
Declare
Max_Bonus   products.Quantity%TYPE;     
begin
select st.Quantity * 0.1
INTO MaxBonus
from product p, Stock st
Where
p.warehousenum = st.W_no
AND
p.p_no = st.p_no;
if :new.Bonus > Max_Bonus then
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20512, 'sales rep’s yearly bonus may not exceed 0.1%  . ');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: For starters 0.1% is `* 0.001`. And do you mean % of quantity or of $ value?

Comment: total value of stock. thank you for your help :)

Comment: can you please tell the relation between employee table with any of table  product, Stock

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a problem with your declaration,

```
Declare
Max_Bonus   products.Quantity%TYPE; ********* it should be product.Quantity      
begin
select st.Quantity * 0.1
```

Table name is mentioned as `products` instead of `product`

Comment: can you brief the error which you get? I ll try to help you out.